# Почему не работает вложенный цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача.  Мы читаем cvs файл. Потом пользователь вводит название стран, а наш код должен найти информацию по этим странам. Вот код, только я не понимаю, почему for row проходит один раз, а print i столько раз сколько елементов в массиве.

```
import csv

with open('Data.csv', newline='') as File:

    reader = csv.reader(File)

    for row in reader:

        print(row)

x = []
g = 0
while g != "end":
    g = input("Country?\n")
    x.append(g)

with open('Data.csv', newline='') as File:

    reader = csv.reader(File)
    myData = []
    for i in x:
        print(i)
        for row in reader:
            if i == row[0]:
                myData.append(row)
                #print("Writing complete")
                print("Out:", row)


myFile = open('example2.csv', 'w')
with myFile:
        writer = csv.writer(myFile)
        writer.writerow(myData)
```

Comment: Нужно ли добавить cvs файл?

Comment: Я не знаю, какие у Вас входные данные, попробовал создать похожие условия из обычных списков на вход и таких же циклов. Всё работает исправно.
Возможно проблема в том, что в reader приходит обычный элемент списка, а не вложенный в ещё один список. У Вас указано row[0], что берёт только первую букву слова в цикле, если там строка. 
Попробуйте убрать индекс в скобках

Comment: Да, нужно все таки добавлять файлы. А то как мне помоч, эсли я не даю исходных данных. В row[0] находилось слова. а не буква. Извините, что потратитил ваше время в пустую, ребята)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы про вот этот фрагмент:

```
for i in x:
        print(i)
        for row in reader:
            if i == row[0]:
                myData.append(row)
                #print("Writing complete")
                print("Out:", row)
```

то `print(i)` сработает столько раз, сколько названий стран пользователь ввел.
А вот  `print("Out:", row)` сработает только тогда, когда  `i == row[0]`. И тут возникает вопрос. `reader` -  это итеритуемый объект. На каждой итерации берется одно его значение и помещается в объект `row`. Объект этот -  строка. А вот `row[0]` - это первая буква этой строки. И получается, что вы `i` сравниваете с одной литерой. Скорее всего они никогда не совпадут.

Comment: Не очень понял, но там просто дело было в том что я один раз открывал файл для чтения и поле первого прохода указатель уходил в конец и на втором проходе он все еще был в конце, а там не с чем сравнить. Может примерно это вы и имели ввиду, но с проблемой я разобрался, а вам спасибо за ответ <3

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('Data.csv', newline='') as File:
    reader = csv.reader(File)

    for row in reader:
        print(row)

x = []
g = 0
while g != "end":
    g = input("Country?\n")
    x.append(g)


myData = []
for i in x:
    print(i)
    with open('Data.csv', newline='') as File:
        reader = csv.reader(File)
        for row in reader:
            if i == row[0]:
                myData.append(row)
                print("Out:", row)

myFile = open('example2.csv', 'w')
with myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerow(myData)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Я не работал с библиотекой `csv`, и могу ошибаться, но у меня есть подозрение, что метод `reader` проходится по файлу один раз, и после того, как он достиг конца файла, он уже не будет читать его ещё раз сначала.

Возможно, имеет смысл создавать копию содержимого файла, и дальше итерироваться уже по ней.

То есть вот эту строку:

```
reader = csv.reader(File)
```

замените на такую:

```
reader = list(csv.reader(File))
```

Этот способ должен хорошо работать, для случая когда размер файла относительно небольшой (например, не больше десятков мегабайт, или сколько там вы можете позволить себе хранить в оперативной памяти).

Для очень больших файлов, возможно, лучше будет каждый раз открывать файл заново уже внутри цикла. То есть вот эту часть:

```
with open('Data.csv', newline='') as File:

    reader = csv.reader(File)
```

поместить уже после строки

```
for i in x:
```